# не получается перейти на другую страницу с помощью поля ввода selenium

Tags: selenium

````
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome



driver = uc.Chrome()
url = 'https://zoon.ru/msk/vet/'
driver.get(url = url)

time.sleep(1)

elem_poisk = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@data-uitest="header-select-city-input"]')

elem_poisk.click()
elem_poisk.send_keys('Красноярск')

#В ПЕРВОМ способе   В ПОЛЕ  ВВОДА НАЗВАНИЕ ВВОДИТ И НЕ НАЖИМАЕТ на  вводящуюся имя города в виде кнопки

VIBOR_GOROD = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="js-city-select-results-wrapper"]').find_element(By.NAME, 'a')

#АРГУМЕНТЫ  ПОИСКА  МЕНЯЛ  НО БЕСТОЛКУ

VIBOR_GOROD.click()# На которое можно нажать , но селениум не  видит и не нажимает

#АРГУМЕНТЫ ПОИСКА ОБЬЕКТА МЕНЯЛ НА КОТОРЫЕ МОГУТ ПОДХОИТЬ

#ВО ВТОРОМ способе ТАКЖЕ ВСЕ ВВОДИТ НО ПРИ НАЖАТИИ НА enter страница просто перезагружалась.
#elem_poisk.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


time.sleep(10)

driver.close()
driver.quit()```

#\ ХОЧУ ПЕРЕЙТИ НАДРУГУЮ СТРАНИЦУ НО не  ВЫХОДИТ .ПОМОГИТЕ ПЖ ЧТО ДЕЛАТЬ 
#что делать в первом способе  и во втором 
#заранее спасибо
````